# Get path of file inside project src and pass it to fileoutputstream for overwriting

Tags: java, properties, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

Successfully accessed a property file via getResourcestream and read using fileinputstream. Now I need to overwrite the same file after appending a new property

**Problem:** stuck getting path of the same file which is required by fileoutputstream for overwriting.

property file is in **src/main/resources.** and trying to update from **src/main/java/com/web/my.class**

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dme.properties");
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
         prop.load(in);}  // load all old properties
    catch (IOException e) {}
    finally {try { in.close(); } catch (IOException e) {} }
    prop.setProperty("a", "b"); //new property
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream("dme.properties");
        prop.store(out, null);} //overwrite
    catch (IOException e) {} 
    finally {try {out.close();} catch (IOException e) {} }
  }
```

Comment: Why not instead of getting the resource as a stream, just get the resource URL. Then, you can read and write from that URL. `URL url = getClass().getResource("/dme.properties");`

Comment: Do not attempt to write to a classpath resource.  It will work while you’re developing in your IDE, but when you run from a .jar, it simply is not possible.  Write your new Properties to a new file under the user’s home directory instead.  Also *never* write an empty catch block.  At the very least, print the stack trace.

Comment: I want to have a global setting in the war file which can be changed by different users. Is there no way to be done via property file apart from database approach ? @VGR

Comment: You cannot write to a .war file or .jar file at runtime.  Writable data must be stored in separate files, or in a database, or in some other data store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getting the `InputStream`, you can get the resource `URL` and use that to read and write with your file from `src/main/resources`:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
File file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/dme.properties").toURI());
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    properties.load(is);
}
properties.setProperty("a", "b");
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    properties.store(os, null);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. URL.getFile() *does not* convert a URL to a file name.  It merely returns the path and query portions of the URL.  (The name ‘getFile’ is due to the nature of URLs back when Java 1.0 was released.)  If the original file name contains spaces or any other characters which are illegal in URLs, the result will not be an existing file name.  Also, when running from a .jar file, it’s impossible to convert a resource URL to a file.

Comment: @VGR - Thanks for the info. I've updated to use a proper `File`. Also, I'm not sure how OP will be using this code so if they are using it from a .jar, I understand your point on this not working. I just was answering their initial question.